# Recursive tokenizer in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am working an assignment in Haskell, to prepare for tests. The current task asks to tokenize a string after the following formula:
When running "tokenize str separate remove" it should should output a list of strings. Every character in "str" appearing in string "separate" should be a string of one character. Every character in "str" appearing in string "remove" should be removed. Characters not appearing in either separate or remove should be bundled together.

Example shows that

```
tokenize "a + b* 12-def"   "+-*"   " "
```

should output

```
["a", "+", "b", "*", "12", "-", "def"]
```

my current code below

```
tokenize :: String -> String -> String -> [String]
tokenize [] _ _  = []
tokenize [x] _ _ = [[x]]
tokenize (x:xs) a b     | x `elem` a = [x] : tokenize xs a b
                        | x `elem` b = tokenize xs a b
                        | otherwise = (x:head rest) : tail rest
                                where
                                        rest = tokenize xs a b
```

It works to some extent, the problem being that it the operators in the example is bundled with the letter preceding it.

like this

```
["a+","b*","12-","def"]
```

despite the operators being in the separate string.

Comment: The problem is in the line `| otherwise = (x:head rest) : tail rest` where you cons `x` on `head rest` no matter what `head rest` may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `tokenize [x] _ _` is probably not what you want, because `tokenize "a" "" "a"` ends up being `["a"]` when it should probably be `[]`. Second, don't call the separator and removal lists `String`s. They are just `[Char]`s. There is no difference underneath, because `type String = [Char]`, but the point of a synonym is to make a semantic meaning clearer, and you are not really using your `String`s as `String`s, so your function isn't worthy of it. Additionally, you should shuffle the arguments to `tokenize seps rems str`, because that makes currying easier. Finally, you probably want to use `Data.Set` instead of `[Char]`, but I won't use it here to stay closer to the question.

The issue itself is `| otherwise = (x:head rest) : tail rest`, which tacks any unspecial character onto the next token, even if that token is supposedly a separator. In your case, an example of this is when `head rest = "+"` and `x = 'a'`, and you join them so you have `"a+"`. You need to guard further.

(Also: your indentation is messed up: `where` clauses bind to the *entire* equation, so it's visible throughout all the guards. It should be indented such that that's clear.)

```
tokenize :: [Char] -> [Char] -> String -> [String]
tokenize _ _ "" = []
tokenize seps rems (x:xs)
  | x `elem` rems                      = rest
  | x `elem` seps                      = [x]:rest
  -- Pattern guard: if rest has a single-char token on top and that token is a sep...
  | ([sep]:_) <- rest, sep `elem` seps = [x]:rest
  -- Otherwise, if rest has a token on top (which isn't a sep), grow it
  | (growing:rest') <- rest            = (x:growing):rest'
  -- Or else make a new token (when rest = [])
  | otherwise                          = [x]:rest
  where rest = tokenize seps rems xs
```

You may also use `filter`:

```
tokenize seps rems = tokenize' . filter (not . flip elem rems)
  where tokenize' "" = []
        tokenize' (x:xs)
          | x `elem` seps                      = [x]:rest
          | ([sep]:_) <- rest, sep `elem` seps = [x]:rest
          | (growing:rest') <- rest            = (x:growing):rest'
          | otherwise                          = [x]:rest
          where rest = tokenize' xs
```